# Azure Boards work item: send email if unactioned after period of time

Tags: azure, devops, workitem, azure-boards

Is it possible to set an an automated email to be sent to a specified email address if an Azure Board work item hasn't been actioned within a specified time range?

i.e. if no action has been done on a work item for 5 days, send myself an email.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the workaround to automate this work is to use logicapps where I have tried to retrieve the `Change Date` for a desired work item and used `dateDifference` function to calculate the difference with today's date. When the difference is more than 5 days I tried to trigger an email. Below is the flow that worked for me.

[image]

Below is the expression I used for comparision

```
int(slice(string(dateDifference(body('Get_work_item_details')?['fields']?['System_ChangedDate'],utcNow())),0,2))
```

#### **RESULTS:**

---

***Successful Run***

[image]

***In my Inbox***

[image]